# Foundation 6 - Console Warning : Tried to initialize magellan (any JS plugin) on an element that already has a Foundation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, bower

I installed `Foundation 6` using `bower`. I keep getting multiple `warning` in the console every-time I use any `Foundation 6 - JavaScript based plugin`.

Exact warning :

> Tried to initialize magellan on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.

My script includes look like:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/what-input/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).foundation();  
</script>
```

The warning is triggered by the following code present in `foundation.js` at line `180` :

```
// For each plugin found, initialize it
    $elem.each(function () {
      var $el = $(this),
          opts = {};
      // Don't double-dip on plugins
      if ($el.data('zfPlugin')) {
        console.warn("Tried to initialize " + name + " on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.");
        return;
      }
```

I have tried `re-installing` from scratch but it still doesn't work. 
Similar question exists in Zurb Foundation Forum but till now there is no good answer.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, but on a reveal!  And its causing a malfunction in the reveal itself.  It handles an image that is updated through a scope variable.  After you click on the reveal once it doesnt update again."Tried to initialize reveal on an element that already has a Foundation plugin."

Comment: @BGecko : I resolved the issue. It is occurring because I have mentioned `$(document).foundation();` at the end of my html and also in my `app.js`. Remove either one of these and the warning goes off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**For Version 6.4.***, all `plugins` and `js` based elements tend to work **only** if `$(document).foundation();` is mentioned within the `html` file. So delete it from `app.js` if you have written in it. For additional reasons, go through the explanation below.

---

Although I have mentioned the answer long back in the `comments` of the question, I felt it will be better to write it up with few more points.

While installing `Zurb Foundation 6` using `bower` (command line), it gives you a nice `index.html` page to get started which has the `<script>` tag that refers to an `external` js file located at `root\js\app.js`. The `app.js` file by default has the following code:

```
$(document).foundation(); //invoke all jQuery based Foundation elements
```

So basically, you already have everything to get started.

But, this wasn't the way how it worked until Foundation 6 and I wasn't aware of these changes. I didn't go through the contents of `app.js` as I was assuming it to be **empty**.  I simply did the old way of invoking them in my `html` pages by writing the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

This kind of *double* referred the jQuery based Foundation elements raising a `warning` at the browser console.

**Solution was to remove either of the invocation**, but actually removing the code written in `external` js file makes more sense for the following reasons:

1. External references cost an additional `http` request, very slightly *increasing* the precious page load time. Why not reduce it, if you can.
2. Invoking jQuery based elements in the site has to be done as early as possible so that every element gets the original shape in no time. So it makes more sense to mention the invocation within a html page rather than request a external file to invoke.
   So, **remove the code mentioned in the external js file**, that is your `app.js` file. The warnings would vanish.
3. **For Version 6.4.***, all `plugins` and `js` based elements tend to work **only** if mentioned within the `html` file.

Comment: **Listen to him!** I also never had `$(document).foundation();` two times and thought it would be unlogical to put this into the end of the html file, instead of the external javascript-file. (also loaded at the end of the html-file) But you was right, the error messages vanished. In my case it was `$.ajax()`-related actions which triggered the Initialize-Foundation error messages. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this problem is to put ***`$(document).foundation();`*** inside **`<script>`** tag under **`.html`** file, and remove it form external `.js` file (`app.js`)

Like this-,

in

> **`xyz.html`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

other solution like, putting it inside external `.js` file (`app.js`), and removing it from `.html` file, will not always works.

at least it didn't work for me.

Tested on-

> foundation version 6.4.2

Comment: Isn't that what even I have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Hari Harker  yes you have mentioned it, but you said to remove either of the invocation and it will work .But in my case only one way it works (by putting inside .html page itself), and other way it does not works at all (putting inside .js file). That's why I stated it in straightforward manner, - and thanks for your reply.

Comment: Just checked. For versions `6.4.*`, it only works if mentioned within the `html` page.